# Ember.js Fixture findQuery

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to change my URLs in Ember to use a property on a model (title), instead of the ID.  I can get everything to work if I click on a link-to, but when I do a fresh reload of the models route, everything seems to fall apart.  Within queryFixtures I can get return the desired item, and [image: this] logs to the console by logging 'experiment' to the console in the model hook.

```
App.ExperimentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    serialize: function(experiment, params) {
        return {
            experiment_title: experiment.get('urlFriendlyName')
        }
    },
    model : function(params) {
        experiment = this.get('store').find('experiment', { title: params.experiment_title });
        return experiment;
    }
});
```

My store:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
        queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query, type) {

            function urlFriendlyTitle(title) {
                var ret = title.replace(/ /g,"-"); // replace spaces
                // do other replacements that make sense in your case, e.g.:
                ret = ret.replace(/&/g,"and");
                //... and so on and so forth
                // encode the remaining characters
                ret = ret.toLowerCase();
                ret = encodeURIComponent(ret);
                return ret;
            }
            return fixtures.filter(function(item) {
                if(urlFriendlyTitle(item.title) == query.title) {
                    // console.log(item);
                    return item;
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
App.ExperimentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
        experiment = this.get('store').find('experiment', {     });
        console.log(Ember.inspect(experiment))
        return experiment;
    }
});
```

Running the above outputs '`<DS.PromiseArray:ember325>`' in the console

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  // Add your routes here
  this.resource('category', { path: '/:category_id'}, function() {
      this.resource('experiment', { path: '/:experiment_title' }, function() {
        this.resource('device', { path: '/:device' });
      });
  });
});

App.ExperimentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        console.log(Ember.inspect(model))
        console.log(Ember.inspect(controller))
    }
})
```

This route outputs `<App.ExperimentController:ember388> <DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray:ember326>`

Comment: "Everything falls apart" is not quite enough- :)  What happens exactly?  Console messages?  When you say you can log in the `model` hook, do you mean in the `Route`?  If so, can you try `console.log(Ember.inspect(experiment))`

Comment: :)  I'm getting no error messages unfortunately. That's precisely what I'm referring to (model hook).  That screenshot is what happens when I console.log(experiment).  I'll try the above and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: I've updated my question to include what you requested in your comment

Comment: OK, so that all looks OK to me...  Please post your `Router` code related to this route.